# HttpSession with default attributes

Tags: spring-mvc, httpsession

Hello i'm developing a Spring web application. I was wondering if it's possible to start/create/instantiate HttpSession with default attributes for example:

```
isLoggedIn : false
```

Once user logs in i will change the value to `true`

Is it possible or should i change my point of view?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could create custom [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) for this:

```
public class CustomSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setAttribute("isLoggedIn", false);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    }
}
```

You can either register it in `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>package.CustomSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Or do it programatically if you use the servlet context initializer approach:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.addListener(CustomSessionListener.class);
}
```

On a side note: I recommend using Spring Security or some existing security framework to handle these things. It's relatively easy to set-up and it will be most likely more secure than any DIY solution.